# How to add Easing Property to this Jquery Scrolling animation

Tags: jquery

Where to add Easing property in following to code to have some cool scrolling animation

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.scrollup').click(function () {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
     return false;
   });
 });
```

Comment: check the DOC: `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easing is the 3rd parameter of the animate function:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000, "linear");
```

---

See the full documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @user3091438 ya, include any library which implement it as e.g jQuery UI because: `easeOutBounce is not part of jquery` (bis!)

Comment: @user3091438 You will need jQuery UI for the majority of the easing options

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000, EASING_HERE);
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/